# Jmeter - Configure Keywords with spaces using CSV File Configuration

Tags: csv, jmeter

I am using Jmeter for load testing a search URL. I am giving the search keywords in a CSV file and running the thread. It works fine when the keywords are single phrase. But it has more than one word i am getting the below error.
     ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl: readResponse: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 505 for URL: http://www.google.com:7080/javaService/search?&queryTerm=**customer service**&sourceName=sharepoint 
ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl: Cause: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 505 for URL: http://www.google.com:7080/javaService/search?&queryTerm=**customer service**&sourceName=sharepoint

Can anyone tell me how we can provide keyword with spaces in CSV file?

My CSV had data as below displaying one sentence/word per line

data handler
scope of work
attendance tracker
customer service

Comment: try using double quotes like "my search"

Comment: I tried "" already. It dint work..

Comment: Try swapping spaces with `%20`.

Comment: Yes i already tried this as well. Not working. my%20search is the keyword i tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A space cannot be present in HTTP GET path or query.

You need to encode query parameters which contain spaces. There are several options on how this can be done:

1. Check "Encode?" box in "Send Parameters with the Request" input of [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)
2. Wrap your variable in [__urlEncode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) function as `${__urlencode(queryTerm)}`
3. Use [Beanshell Pre Processor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) as a child of HTTP Request with the following code:

   ```
   vars.put("queryTerm", URLEncoder.encode(vars.get("queryTerm")));
   ```

Any of above options will convert space to either "+" or "%20" which should resolve your issue.

Comment: @ Dmitri T - I tried the above steps. Now i am getting error% as 0 in Summary report. It worked perfectly!! Thanks!!

Comment: Good to know that it was helpful. Good luck.

Comment: @DmitriT Can you please be more clearer , as in here in the solution, what is "queryTerm", can you explain it more clearly

Comment: JMeter variable name, it can be accessed as `${queryTerm}` where required

Comment: @DmitriT, i have to encode say ABC%20desc, how do i put this in my parameters, will it be ${__urlencode(ABC%20desc)} ??

Comment: it seems to be encoded already. You can use [Function Helper Dialog](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) to get function syntax hints. Also check out [Using JMeter Functions](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733749-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-I) article

Comment: If i pass it as "ABC%20desc" it gives me a 434 error, can you please help me out on how i should tackle this as all my tests are failing because of this, should i pass it as "ABC%20desc" or "ABC desc" or ${__urlencode(ABC%20desc)} or ${__urlencode(ABC desc)}??