# How to make jmeter convert |(pipe) to %7C automatically?

Tags: url, uri, jmeter

I am getting following error whenever Jmeter gets a | (pipe) symbol in  the URL since the "pipe" symbol is not allowed in URL. Is there any way to convert the |(pipes) in URL to %7C automatically?

`Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the pipe is in an existing parameter try the following:

1. Check "Encode?" box in "Send Parameters with the Request" input of [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)
2. Wrap your variable in [__urlEncode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) function as `${__urlencode(queryTerm)}`
3. Use [Beanshell Pre Processor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) as a child of HTTP Request with the following code:

   ```
   vars.put("queryTerm", URLEncoder.encode(vars.get("queryTerm")));
   ```

This should convert the pipes automatically.

Got the instructions from here: [Jmeter - Configure Keywords with spaces using CSV File Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23908846/jmeter-configure-keywords-with-spaces-using-csv-file-configuration)

Comment: What if the pipe is not in my parameter? I am actually giving path to a site and retrieving all the embeddable object. Images on that site have pipes in their URL. What to do about that?

Comment: @Pranay Well don't encode the term, encode the whole URL. Your URL must be in some sort of JMeter variable, in which case use the code above on it. Have you even tried anything?